# word-wrap in div with display:inline-block doesn't work

Tags: css, word-wrap

I've been trying to figure out how to make a row with 4 colums using div-elements.

The first and the third column should be 46px wide. The second and fourth column should be 50%  of the left place (like 100% window width - 46*2) wide. I realized that already as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5p5V9/) in the first grey box.

Well, the text of the second and fourth column can be longer and I want it to break in the div .

The second grey box shows you how it looks like when the text is longer.
The third grey box shows you another try with 'display:table-cell'. The only problem is that the width of 50% of the second column just decreases while the width of the fourth column increases.

I need both columns to have the same width. Have you got an idea how I to achieve it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/5p5V9/1/ If so, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you a thousand times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to adapt your `display: table-cell` version.

The most important change was adding `table-layout: fixed`. [What that does](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#fixed-table-layout) is equally distribute the remaining available width between the columns without a specified `width`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/5p5V9/2/

**CSS:**

```css
.outer {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #373737;
}

.inner {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.inner > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
.alignC {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #949494;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
.first, .alignC {
    width: 46px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.alignR, .alignL {
    background: #666;
}​
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="first">1</div>
        <div class="alignR">r</div>
        <div class="alignC">m</div>
        <div class="alignL">This long text shall break in the div</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Browser support for `display: table-cell`.](http://caniuse.com/css-table)

Comment: Again...thank you. Great idea. Never would've figure it out on my own.

Comment: Thats a nice option. Performance people had been advising not to use table element (not the table css feature). Reason being its complex percentage calculations on all rows and cells. Besides, not a good idea for presentation/code/documentation technically. That is what i had been reading and hearing. The time taken for rendering tables, and table cells will cost performance(i mean using the elements). I have experiences it and after changing it to div's it worked good. The question is ... is using styles like table, table-cell, etc a good practice? w.r.t. standard, performance, etc... ?